# Get 100 as an answer on a calculator without using 0

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

**Task**

Get 100 as an answer with only four keystrokes on a regular calculator.

**Disallowed keys**

- 0
- 00

**Allowed keys**

All other than the aforementioned two keys.

Take the below image as a reference.
[image: Regular Calculator]

**Condition**

Atleast two operators must be used.

Comment: This question can be found a few different times online: https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111021032155AA4ke5E & https://www.quora.com/How-can-one-get-100-by-typing-just-three-buttons-in-calculator-without-using-zero you have just added the two operator condition

Comment: Does pressing = count?

Comment: @theonlygusti Yes

Comment: Might I suggest "only four keystrokes" instead of "only four buttons" in the wording of this.  I could easily complete this task using 1=1+ and simply hammer the "=" sign until 100 is shown on the display.  Don't make it easy for the devious :)

Comment: Scientific calculator allowed or basic calculator only? Also, must every press have a purpose?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 I don't think scientific ones are allowed. See the reference image in the picture. (Of course, ultimately it's up to Nikhil whether or not to allow them.)

Comment: @servaes = is considered as an operator here

Comment: Not this calculator, but `1 E 2 =`

Comment: On the windows10 *standard* calculator: `.` `1` `x^2` `1/x` or `.` `1` `1/x` `x^2`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

On my actual junky little calculator, these four button presses give 100:

> **$1$**
>  **$\div$**
>  **$\%$**
>  **$=$**
>
>  In fact, any non-zero digit will work.  Calculators will just use the current value in the display as the operand if you didn't type a new one, so what you're doing is saying:  Start with $1$.  Divide it by ... (*the still displayed*) $1$ turned into $1\%$, or $0.01$.  Then hitting $=$ gives the answer of $100$.

Also, try it here:
https://www.theonlinecalculator.com/
which behaves the same way.

Comment: How is this possible?

Comment: It works on Windows 10 default calculator too. Nice!

Comment: @NikhilBhavar 1 divided by 0.01 = 100

Comment: I got that. How does this work? For instance, what is 5÷%= ?

Comment: It works because the calculator does 1 / (1%). 5 / % is 5 / (5%), which is 0.25, so 5 / 0.25 = 20

Comment: @CalvT 5% is .05.  5 / .05 is still 100.

Comment: @Rubio I get 20, as I get 5% of 5, which is 0.25, so 5 / 0.25

Comment: @Siguza Looks like you hit "$+$" (PLUS)  instead of  "$\div$" (DIVIDE)?

Comment: the percent key means "take x% of the preceding result", so 5 / (5%) is 5 / (5% of 5) = 5 / 0.25 = 20

Comment: @Rubio Oooh, I see. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRCvy.png) is what the post looks like for me... hard to tell apart from **+**.

Comment: @ffao Actually the $\%$ key on a calculator just means "divide by 100", and it does exactly that. (Following addition/subtraction it gets a little weirder, but following multiplication/division that's all it is.) Try it on the calculator site I posted.  $5 \div \% =$ will give $100$.

Comment: I guess the only consensus about the % button is that there is no consensus about what the % button does. :)

Comment: Meh. I'm not happy with this answer. My phone calculator tells me "wrong format" when I tried this. (Not your fault, this is the only solution that anyone seems to have come up with, and accepted by the OP...)

Comment: @Shokhet Try with a real-life cheap calculator, not software implementations. The fancy solutions that work on a phone calculator don't work on real calculators.

Comment: The thing is, actual calculators will keep the last number entered for use with the result. The number you entered goes in the first accumulator (let's call it A) and the second number entered (or the result in this case) goes in the second accumulator (let's call that B). Pressing 1 and then ÷ initiates the operation so A has 1 in it, but this does not conclude it because it needs an input from B, when you press % the number in A is used with the operand % and written into B. Now, A has 1 in it and B has 0.01, as soon as you press = the calculation of ÷ is completed and the result is 100.

Answer (score 15):

It is

> 1/1%

because

> 1/1 = 1 and 1 expressed as a percentage would be 100%. Note that I didn't have to press the = sign in my calculator to get to the 100.

Comment: You need to hit = to make this give the result, which would be a fifth keypress

Comment: Unless they mean 'press 4 buttons' meaning any number of presses but you can only use 4 different keys (1, /, %, =)

Comment: 1 in percentage is 0.01

Comment: @Sconibulus Didn't think about it coz my calc calculated it without pressing the = sign :/

Comment: @NikhilBhavar corrected.

Comment: Both this one and Rubio's work on Win 7 calc. Although like you this is the one I came up with.

Comment: = is a fifth button press. Similarly, there's 4x25 (which is the one that I came up with, until I saw the OP's [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51642/get-100-as-an-answer-on-a-calculator-without-using-0#comment158227_51642) that mentioned that = counts as a button press. +1 anyway.

Comment: On several calculators, this gives 0.01 instead of 100.

Comment: On many calculators it is not neccessary to press the '=' after using the '%' - it was it's own equal.

Answer (score 5):

I found another solution.

> .1 first and second key, 1/x third key, x<sup>2</sup> fourth key. You need a calculator with those buttons though.

The OP says that calculator is just for reference, meaning I can use "a regular calculator" that's slightly different?
It's the standard calculator that came with my windows 10.

Answer (score -3):

On the Windows 7 default calculator the following works

> 1 % =          But then again you have to add the / to make it two operators I guess

Comment: Then this is the same as @Rubio's answer, no?

Comment: Don't you mean `1/%=` and not `1%=`?

Comment: Interesting, this only works if you had been playing with the other method beforehand. Therefore when you hit 1/%= then proceed to hit 1%= it works but not otherwise, can anyone explain what carries over from the first equation to make the second one work? I always assumed it started with a new calculation after you hit equals unless you continue with a new operator.

Answer (score -4):

You can do it with 3 mouse clicks on a virtual claculator (Windows or Mac):

> With the calculator in "programmer" mode, base 16 selected, click 6 4 "base 10"

And for the pedants that require *2* "operators":

> With the calculator in "programmer" mode, base 16 selected, click 6 4 "base 10" =

Comment: This doesn't use the keys  shown on the reference calculator.

Comment: -1.  Not a "regular calculator", and you did not use two operators, both of which are indicated in the puzzle.

Comment: @Rubio I know. But lots of answers on this site "band the rules". I still like my answer.

Comment: Then I could "bend the rules" by choosing to ignore the rules I don't like also.  My solution is thus:  $1 \ \ 0 \ \ 0$, *et voila*.  (Yeah, you can't just toss away the rules, or anarchy wins!)

Comment: There is no lateral thinking tag which means, don't bend the rules to the question.

Answer (score -5):

> You can press `25 x 4` to get 100.

Comment: That wouldn't work; you'd need to press the `=` key as well. (The calculator might think you want to type 25x41=)

Comment: (Also doesn't use two operators, as required.)

Comment: *"That wouldn't work; you'd need to press the = key as well."*  It will work with an RPN calcluator:  `25<enter>4*`

Comment: You used five keystrokes total.

Comment: @radarbob Nope, 2, 5, Enter, 4, * is 5 keystrokes.

Comment: Hay, I'm using base 6. That means there is no carry.

Comment: (Also doesn't use two operators, as required.) — 1 * 25 * 4.